# Adjust newtcolorbox to text width in one or multiple lines

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox

I'm trying to make an "example" `tcolorbox` which adjusts to its text width. I've tried `hbox` but it fails when we have multiple lines.

Using `hbox`

[image]

Without using `hbox`

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Yes, I've managed to get my expected solution, but creating another "example" `tcolorbox`. I'd like to use only one.

Here's my compilable example (first image):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcbtheorem[]{exa}{EXAMPLE}{
    hbox,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, fontupper=\normalsize,
    theorem style=standard,
    enhanced,frame hidden,
    boxrule=0pt,
    left=0.2cm,top=0.2cm, toptitle=0.1cm+1pt,bottomtitle=-0.1cm+0.5em,
    bottomrule=1pt,
    colback=white,coltitle=orange,
    title style=white,
    titlerule=1pt, titlerule style=orange,
    borderline south={1pt}{0pt}{orange}
}{exa}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{exa}{}{}
    hello
\end{exa}   

\begin{exa}{}{}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{exa}   
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about defining two different environments that share the same counter?

Comment: @leandriis That's the problem, I'm looking for only one newtcolorbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

- a new command `\newtcboxtheorem` based on `\tcbox`, is provided and
- the choice key `tcbox width` is extended to accept value `auto limited with title counted`, which will make the width of output `\tcbox` be `min("/tcb/width", max(upper, title))`.

By default, `\tcbox` defines a new command (the `\exabox` in the following example), hence the environment-version is also provided, which makes the input for
starred/unnumbered theorem easier.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, theorems}

\makeatletter
\def\newtcboxtheorem{%
  \let\@@newtcolorbox\newtcbox
  \new@tcbtheorem}

\tcbset{
  tcbox width/auto limited with title counted/.code={\tcb@set@embed@tcbox{%
    \setbox\z@=\color@hbox##1\color@endbox
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\color@hbox\kvtcb@fonttitle\kvtcb@before@title\kvtcb@title\kvtcb@after@title\color@endbox
    \@tempdima=\wd\z@
    \@tempdimb=\wd\@tempboxa
    \ifdim\@tempdima<\tcb@w@upper\relax
      \ifdim\@tempdima<\@tempdimb
        \begin{minipage}{\@tempdimb}##1\end{minipage}%
      \else
        \box\z@
      \fi
    \else
      \begin{minipage}{\tcb@w@upper}##1\end{minipage}%
    \fi}}
}
\makeatother

\newtcboxtheorem{exabox}{EXAMPLE}{
    tcbox width=auto limited with title counted,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, fontupper=\normalsize,
    theorem style=standard,
    enhanced,frame hidden,
    boxrule=0pt,
    left=0.2cm,top=0.2cm, toptitle=0.1cm+1pt,bottomtitle=-0.1cm+0.5em,
    bottomrule=1pt,
    colback=white,coltitle=orange,
    title style=white,
    titlerule=1pt, titlerule style=orange,
    borderline south={1pt}{0pt}{orange}
}{exa}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exa}{ O{} m m +b }{%
  \exabox[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exa*}{ O{} m +b }{%
  \csname exabox*\endcsname[#1]{#2}{#3}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\def\dummy{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
}

\subsection*{Using command \texttt{\textbackslash exabox[*]}}
\exabox{}{}{short}

\exabox{}{}{long long longer than title}

\exabox{}{}{\dummy}

\csname exabox*\endcsname{}{unnumbered}

\subsection*{Using environment \texttt{exa[*]}}
\begin{exa}{}{}
  short
\end{exa}

\begin{exa}{}{}
  long long longer than title
\end{exa}

\begin{exa}{}{}
  \dummy
\end{exa}

\begin{exa*}{}
  unnumbered
\end{exa*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One possible way forward is to make a new theorem command based on `\tcbox` which can then make use of the `varwidth upper` option.

Something like this, where I've made a new `\tcboxtheorem` macro, which could be used to define `\exa` and `\exastar` for numbered and unnumered theorems:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins}

\makeatletter
% \newtcboxtheorem[init options]{name}{display name}{options}{prefix}
\newcommand{\newtcboxtheorem}[5][]{%
  \newtcbox[auto counter,#1]{#2}[3][]{%
    #4,
    varwidth upper,
    title={\tcb@theo@title{#3}{\thetcbcounter}{##2}},
    list entry={\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}##2},
    nameref={##2},
    code={\tcb@theo@label{#5}{##3}},
    ##1
  }%
  \newtcbox[#1,no counter,list inside=]{#2star}[2][]{%
    #4,
    varwidth upper,
    title={\tcb@theo@title{#3}{\@empty}{##2}},
    ##1}%
}
\makeatother

\newtcboxtheorem[]{exa}{EXAMPLE}{
  fonttitle=\bfseries, fontupper=\normalsize,
  theorem style=standard,
  enhanced, frame hidden,
  boxrule=0pt,
  left=0.2cm, top=0.2cm, toptitle=0.1cm+1pt, bottomtitle=-0.1cm+0.5em,
  bottomrule=1pt,
  colback=white, coltitle=orange,
  title style=white,
  titlerule=1pt, titlerule style=orange,
  borderline south={1pt}{0pt}{orange}
}{exa}

\begin{document}
\exa{Title}{label}{hello}
\exastar{Title}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I've edited my post. The important detail in my "expected" image is not the numbered title but the size of the box @David Purton

Comment: @Á.Iborra, that's what my answer does. `\exa` with give you big or small boxes depending on the content.